# How do I return null for missing xml parameters from API

Tags: python, xml, parsing, null

I am pulling data from the following site and creating a series of lists with the results which ultimately get appended into a dataframe. When the data is missing from my requests it won't write Nope in the list which leads to misalignment of tabular data. The lists can contain from 40 to 46 items depending.

```
for element in callsignlist:
    r = requests.get(f'https://xmldata.qrz.com/xml/current/?s={key};callsign={element}')
    root = ET.fromstring(r.content)

    for elm in root.findall(".//{http://xmldata.qrz.com}call"):
        result = elm.text
        if result == "":
            callsign.append("Nope")
        else:
            callsign.append(result)
            

    for elm in root.findall(".//{http://xmldata.qrz.com}fname"):
        result = None
        result = elm.text
        if result == "":
            name.append("Nope")
        else:
            name.append(result)
```

I have tried to use is not amongst a variety of other items within if statements which I figured would trigger writing None into the list. Nothing seems to accomplish it though. Any help is appreciated.

Here is a copy of r.content as requested. My script goes through and pulls various callsigns and gets their data however some users don't fill in an email for example and so my data gets all messed up as the name wont correlate to a proper email or address. Ideally, I just want to build a database of user info for my contacts in Ham Radio.

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>\n<QRZDatabase version="1.36" xmlns="http://xmldata.qrz.com">\n<Callsign>\n<call>VA6TI</call>\n<dxcc>1</dxcc>\n<nickname>Ty</nickname>\n<fname>Tyler</fname>\n<name>Kacsor</name>\n<addr1></addr1>\n<addr2>Lethbridge</addr2>\n<state>AB</state>\n<zip></zip>\n<country>Canada</country>\n<lat></lat>\n<lon></lon>\n<grid>DN39or</grid>\n<ccode>49</ccode>\n<land>Canada</land>\n<qslmgr>LOTW</qslmgr>\n<email>testuser@gmail.com</email>\n<u_views>1064</u_views>\n<bio>1253</bio>\n<biodate>2022-11-06 22:18:05</biodate>\n<image>https://cdn-xml.qrz.com/i/va6ti/IMG_7281.jpg</image>\n<imageinfo>1200:900:634993</imageinfo>\n<moddate>2022-08-19 19:33:24</moddate>\n<eqsl>1</eqsl>\n<mqsl>1</mqsl>\n<cqzone>4</cqzone>\n<ituzone>2</ituzone>\n<geoloc>user</geoloc>\n<name_fmt>Tyler "Ty" Kacsor</name_fmt>\n</Callsign>\n<Session>\n<Key></Key>\n<Count>8757</Count>\n<SubExp>Mon Oct 16 17:48:33 2023</SubExp>\n<GMTime>Sat Nov 12 16:55:21 2022</GMTime>\n<Remark>cpu: 0.019s</Remark>\n</Session>\n</QRZDatabase>\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking if elm.text is None? What happens when you try to print elm.text? By the way, to be more Pythonic and play nicer with Pandas, append the result as a None data type instead of "Nope".

Comment: share a valid example of `r.content`

Comment: I have tried to check if it is none but still had the same issues. I was thinking perhaps I could introduce a try/except perhaps? If I try to print elm.text it will print text when its returned otherwise it prints nothing. I've used a few if constructs that I figured would correct this but so far I'm unsuccessful.

Comment: You may have empty whitespace or control characters like line breaks. Try: `if elm.text.strip() == ""`.